# Behavior of floated object when related element is missing

Tags: css

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php if($page->hasPrevVisible()): ?>
    <span class="prev">
        <em>Previous Article</em>
        <a href="<?php echo $page->prevVisible()->url() ?>"><?php echo $page->prevVisible()->title() ?></a>
    </span>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($page->hasNextVisible()): ?>
    <span class="next">
        <em>Next Article</em>
        <a href="<?php echo $page->nextVisible()->url() ?>"><?php echo $page->nextVisible()->title() ?></a>
    </span>
    <?php endif ?>  
</div>
```

This is what stands in my article view, basically. There's the main div, which won't matter for this case and two spans within. When there's no next our previous article, the option doesn't show up. Now to the CSS:

```
.pagination em {
font-family: Arvo;
font-size: .8em;
font-style: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: block;
color: #838383;
}

.prev {
width: 49%;
display: inline-block;
}

.next {
width: 49%;
text-align: right;
float: right;
}
```

I've included the `.pagination em` because it is really important for me to keep that `display:block` there to drop a line. I can't make `.next` align with `.prev` without using float, it goes one line down. So maybe the issue is in the `em`, but I don't know for sure.

If there is a previous and a next article, it works like a charm. If there is only a previous article it also stands perfectly, however, if there's solely a next article, `.next` won't align properly.

For a practical example, please take a look at the bottom of this [page](http://philgr.com/blog/Designing-the-logo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `.pagination` class is not clearing with only one floated div in it.

If you simply add `overflow: auto;` to the `.pagination` class in your CSS, it should fix the problem.

```
.pagination {
    padding: 1.25em 0px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    border-bottom: 0.07143em solid rgb(55, 185, 81);
    font-family: "Elena Web",Georgia;

    overflow: auto;
}
```

Example: http://cssdesk.com/q2h4U

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

`float` will float the element out of parent's "inner" dimension, which means its size will not be considered when calculating parent's size.

You can use `display:inline-block` on both sides, and use a dummy `span` when only one side is present:

http://jsfiddle.net/WR6cy/

```
<!-- when both sides present -->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="prev">
        <em>Previous Article</em>
        <a href="#">Previous Title</a>
    </span>
    <span class="next">
        <em>Next Article</em>
        <a href="#">Next Title</a>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- when only prev side presents -->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="prev">
        <em>Previous Article</em>
        <a href="#">Previous Title</a>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- when only next side presents, use a dummy prev side to "push" the next -->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="prev">
    </span>
    <span class="next">
        <em>Next Article</em>
        <a href="#">Next Title</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

```css
.prev {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.next {
    width: 49%;
    text-align: right;
/*    float: right;*/
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Edit**:

To achieve this with your current PHP, you can slightly modify it to:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="prev">
    <?php if($page->hasPrevVisible()): ?>
        <em>Previous Article</em>
        <a href="<?php echo $page->prevVisible()->url() ?>"><?php echo $page->prevVisible()->title() ?></a>
    <?php endif ?>
    </span>

    <span class="next">
    <?php if($page->hasNextVisible()): ?>
        <em>Next Article</em>
        <a href="<?php echo $page->nextVisible()->url() ?>"><?php echo $page->nextVisible()->title() ?></a>
    <?php endif ?>  
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Heya, Actually, creating dummies would lead to further more issues, as it would mean create an entire php template for the single post. Thanks :D